# Does unused jquery link slow down a page

Tags: jquery

The website that I am working with has a global header and has this link included in it:

```
    <script src="/hs/hsstatic/jquery-libs/static-1.1/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>hsjQuery = window['jQuery'];</script>
```

On the pages that do not require jquery, will having the link on all pages slow down page load?

Comment: Just a note - didn't see v1.7. in like 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

No (not really). You download it once, all the other pages you get it from cache which is near-instant. The same applies for all css, js and media like images. If you're new to this concept, I highly recommend you research how to cache everything :)

You can do it one step better: Instead of downloading and hosting jQuery yourself, you can use one of [their CDN options](https://code.jquery.com/). That means that if a user visited *a site* which implements that jQuery version, they have cached it by the time they reach your site.

Also, while every kb makes a difference in theory, one extra JS file wont be noticable on most internet connections.